# Como saber qual versão do jquery foi carregada

Tags: jquery

O código abaixo me exibe perfeitamente se o `jQuery` foi ou não carregado:

```
if (jQuery) {
    $('div#home_login').attr('style', 'background: green');
} else {
    $('div#home_login').attr('style', 'background: red'); }
```

Porém, como faço para saber qual a versão que foi carregada, ou versões, pois tenho alguns plugins que não funcionam com determinadas versões, como por exemplo o `autocomplete` e o `.on` que não funcionam com a mesma versão.

Queria, ao entrar na página, saber qual a versão ou as versões foram carregadas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o comando `$.fn.jquery` para obter uma string com a versão. Note no exemplo, que a versão que será carregada no projeto será sempre a última, nunca será carregada mais de uma versão ao mesmo tempo.

```js
var versaoJquery = $.fn.jquery;
console.log('Versão jQuery: ' + versaoJquery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Fonte: [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/)

Comment: show, funcionou legal, só não sei se exibirá todas as versões carregadas, tomara que sim.